# beta regression creating a wild residual vs. fitted plot- whats going on?

Tags: r, regression, residuals, beta-regression

I recently ran a beta regression model in R using the `betareg` package. I am modeling a continuous dependent variable (a fraction out of 1) that is bound between 0 and 1, as a function of a continuous variable that only takes on positive values. Model code, and code to generate residual vs. fitted is here:

```
fit <- betareg(y ~ x, data=d)
plot(residuals(fit) ~ fitted(fit))
```

The residual vs. fitted plot looks like this:
[image]

So like... what is going on here. Is this normal for beta regression, or have I mis-specified my model somehow?

Histogram of dependent variable, `y`:
[image]

Histogram of independent variable, `x`:
[image]

output from `summary(fit)`

```
Call:
betareg(formula = relEM ~ mat, data = d1)

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0716 -0.3940 -0.1730  0.4468  2.0633 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.863468   0.062820  13.745   <2e-16 ***
mat         -0.053734   0.005667  -9.482   <2e-16 ***

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(phi) 0.261182   0.005735   45.54   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 1.156e+04 on 3 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.03853
Number of iterations: 14 (BFGS) + 1 (Fisher scoring)
```

Comment: To make sense of this, add also the observed versus fitted plot (calibration plot) and some display of the distributions of observed and fitted.

Comment: The big residuals, positive or negative, are where the model is out for  values near 0 or near 1. Then you have a bundle in the middle. As you have just one covariate, a scatter plot of `relEM` versus `mat` should be telling you something similar when you superimpose the fitted curve. As I understand it, you have a weak relationship (the wonderful P-values are just an artefact of large sample size) and over the range of the covariate, the predictions don't vary much, between about 0.4 and about 0.7, so several residuals with absolute value about 0.3 or 0.4 are inevitable.

Comment: @NickCox okay, so the upper and lower lines in the residual plot are the 0 and 1 values, fine. But then why does the plot of residuals exhibit a negative slope? Shouldn't the slope be ~0? You write "over the range of the covariate", do you mean over the range of the independent variable? I dont understand how "so several residuals with absolute value about 0.3 or 0.4 are inevitable" explains the negative slope of the residual plot.

Comment: I'm guessing a bit because you are not showing the data directly which is the most important thing you could do to help interpretation. I don't understand why the highest and lowest residuals are so sharply segregated. I don't use the term "independent variable"; covariate is indeed my corresponding term.  You are not doing linear regression, clearly, and the logit link is complicating things.  If you have responses near 0 and 1 and predictions don't go outside 0.4 to 0.7 that is how you must get some residuals around $\pm$ 0.3 (your plot standardises them to a different scale).

Comment: I have found the same issue when I use the residual function on a beta regression model. Try calculating the residuals, rather than use the stats::residuals function, and the graph will look very different.